# How to have a built-in mini chrome in my android application?

Tags: android, webview

I want to have a mini chrome browser inside my app like Twitter or Telegram does, that 'Powered by Chrome' thing, not a WebView in an Activity.
Also, if some certain users have no Chrome or Google installed, can they use this mini broswer?

Comment: they use this: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs